# The EntityContainer name must be unique in different assemblies?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have two projects:

- News.Data
- Tags.Data

Both define `Entities`. When I try to execute

```
using (var db = new News.Data.Entities("name=Entities"))
{
    results1 = db.News.ToList();
}

using (var db = new Tag.Data.Entities("name=Entities"))
{
    results2 = db.Tag.ToList();
}
```

on a console application I get this error:

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
>   Model1.csdl(3,4) : error 0019: The
>   EntityContainer name must be unique.
>   An EntityContainer with the name
>   'Entities' is already defined.

Is it possible to use

```
News.Data.Entities
Tags.Data.Entities
```

instead of

```
News.Data.NewsEntities
Tags.Data.TagsEntities
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Connectionstrings are configured at application level, and the containername serves as a unique identifier. Either change the containerNames to a unique value, either reimplement the the default constructor of the `ObjectContext` to perhaps lookup a `Setting`, which can be configured at assembly level.</strike>

Edit: 
When creating an instance of an `ObjectContext`, `News.Data.Entities` in this example, the base class of your context is typically constructed with a `ContainerName`. This parameter gives the `ObjectContext` all the necessary information to make its store connection, and do all its mapping business.

Basically, an association is made between the `ObjectContext` type and the `ContainerName`. When instantiating your second context `Tags.Data.Entities`, which is a different type, it will try to associate the type with the container and this is what throws the exception, since you can't associate the same ContainerName twice.

To address the issue, if you can, best thing would be to recreate the EDMX, with different container names. If deleting is not an option, you can modify the ContainerName parameter in the designer, then crack open the edmx in notepad, and look for 'EntitiesModelStoreContainer', and change the 'Entities' part to whatever your new ContainerName is.

Hope it helps...

Comment: The connection is not an issue, the class name is.

Comment: I know, but the container must also be unique at application level. You have two containers with the same `ContainerName`. The fact that it gives you a collision in the configuration should be your first clue. Basically, EF associates the ObjectContext instance with the EDMX for whom you provided the unique identifier(=container name) via its constructor.

Comment: The most helpful portion of the above answers is the detail about opening the EDMX directly in notepad. Visual Studio fails to update the EDMX properly by just changing the container name in the VS property pane. Previous answers to similar questions have failed to point out this detail.

Comment: Crack open the edmx in notepad, change the name, and then refresh the model in the edmx worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I take it you've tried this:

```
using (var db = new News.Data.Entities("name=NewsEntities"))
{
    results1 = db.News.ToList();
}

using (var db = new Tag.Data.Entities("name=TagEntities"))
{
    results2 = db.Tag.ToList();
}
```

Your problem is that the two projects have the same entity container name. You need to change (at least) one of them.

Edit: Sorry, to answer your exact question ... No!

> Is it possible to use
>
> ```
> News.Data.Entities
> Tags.Data.Entities
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```
> News.Data.NewsEntities
> Tags.Data.TagsEntities
> ```

Comment: I'm using the same `connectionstring`. `<add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/;provider=...`

Comment: Ah, I see ... the name= part of the constructor was the connection string to use.

Comment: Ok, well as I said, you do need to have different entity container names. Rename them as you suggested to NewsEntites and TagEntities.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might not be with your logic. I encounter this sometimes when I switch between build profiles. To fix it, I delete all temporary files and do a clean build.