# The EntityContainer name must be unique

Tags: entity-framework, entity

This exception has cost me two days, still no clue.

I have this .net application running on my server, consuming a web service from an assembly.
The assembly is installed in gac with a different version number. After deploying a new version, I am getting this exception:

> Remote Service Connection Exception:
>   Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
>   : The EntityContainer name must be
>   unique. An EntityContainer with the
>   name 'xxxEntities' is already defined.

I have tried cleaning the cache under temporary folder, did not help. Is there a problem with this design, that uses a different version of the assembly to provide services for a different version of clients?

Comment: btw: the xxxx.edmx file is used in the assembly, the exception is thrown when system is trying to create a new instance of xxxxEntity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have much clue about this either, but perhaps it is related to: [The EntityContainer name must be unique in different assemblies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898794/the-entitycontainer-name-must-be-unique-in-different-assemblies)

Comment: useful link. i plan to use different entity name for different assembly now, hope i can get rid of this annoying exception.