# EF 4: System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: Name: Each type name in a schema must be unique

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I want to use EF code first approach.

I have read this post:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

and created my BL classes

```
public class AppData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }

    public AppData_OptionsDialog OptionsDialog { get; set; }

    public AppData_Compatibility Compatibility { get; set; }

}

public class AppData_Compatibility
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Platform { get; set; }

    public string MaxVersion { get; set; }
}


public class AppData_OptionsDialog
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public string AppDesc { get; set; }

    public string PrivacyPolicyUrl { get; set; }

    public string TermsOfUseUrl { get; set; }

}


public class AppsDataContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
    public AppsDataContext() : base("MaMDB") { }

    public DbSet<Conduit.Mam.Common.BlData.AppsData.AppData> AppsData { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Conduit.Mam.Common.BlData.AppsData.AppData_Compatibility> AppData_Compatibilities { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Conduit.Mam.Common.BlData.AppsData.AppData_OptionsDialog> AppData_OptionsDialogs { get; set; }       
}
```

I have created corrisponding tables in the DB.

I understand EF uses convention over configuration.

So is it magically maps the classes to the DB? no need to generate an em

I try to execute a test on of the methods:

```
    public IList<Conduit.Mam.Common.BlData.AppsData.AppData> GetAll()
    {
        var apps = from app in AppsDataContext.AppsData
               select app;

        return apps.ToList();
    }
```

but get the following error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: Name: Each type name in a
>   schema must be unique. Type name 'AppData_OptionsDialog' is already
>   defined. \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: Name: Each type name
>   in a schema must be unique. Type name 'AppData_Compatibility' is
>   already defined.

I have seen this answer, but it didn't help me

[Entity Framework error - "The EntityContainer name must be unique"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979664/entity-framework-error-the-entitycontainer-name-must-be-unique)

Comment: I believe that you need to set Navigation property and / or the properties of AppData class as virtual.

Comment: according to this, nothing ahas to be virtual: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19233/Introduction-to-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm

Comment: You need to specify the Foreign Key Attribute and Key Attribute. @Elad Benda, did you see the "public virtual Category Category {get;set;}" in the link that you post?

Comment: Do you happen to have more than one class named 'AppData_OptionsDialog' in your project? (Even if living in a different namespace)

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what the problem is, even though this is incredibly old, I'm running across the same problem now, it seems EF doesn't like it when you have:

```
public class User_Roles {
    public bool Admin { get; set; }
    public bool Moderator { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
public class User {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Salt { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual User_Roles Roles { get; set; }
}
```

In this case, either User_Roles needs to be renamed or the Roles property in User needs to be renamed, as so:

```
public class URoles {
    public bool Admin { get; set; }
    public bool Moderator { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
public class User {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Salt { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual URoles Roles { get; set; }
}
```

or you could simply change the "Roles" property in User:

```
public class User_Roles {
    public bool Admin { get; set; }
    public bool Moderator { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
public class User {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Salt { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual User_Roles URoles { get; set; }
}
```

in your case, this is happening on:

```
public AppData_OptionsDialog OptionsDialog { get; set; }
public AppData_Compatibility Compatibility { get; set; }
```

Either rename the class, or rename the properties.